# Wrapper function throws "query has no destination for result data" error

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

So, I have the following plpgsql wrapper function that returns void:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EXPORT_DATA(
    Id      IN NUMBER,
    PlanId  IN NUMBER,
    User    IN VARCHAR2,
    Begin   IN DATE,
    End     IN DATE
    )
 RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
 $function$
    BEGIN
        select EXP_DATA(Id,PlanId,User,Begin,End);
    END;
```

`EXP_DATA()` is also a function returning `void` and all that it does, it just uses some cursors and inserts some data in some tables. If called by itself, `EXP_DATA()` works without any problem but when called through a wrapper function. it somehow produces the following error:

> ```
> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
> HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
> ```

I've tried using `perform`, no luck.

Comment: What happened when you used `perform EXP_DATA(Id,PlanId,User,Begin,End);` ?

Comment: Same error as above.

Comment: Then the error is inside your exp_data function. A `perform` call will **not** cause that error

Comment: Please remember to start any such question by declaring the Postgres version in use. Also, the function definition is invalid and incomplete. `user` or `end` etc. are reserved words and cannot be used as function parameters like that. Please post your *actual* function definition. Too much obfuscation here to help you.